# Use Query Name as series Display Name in Grafana

Tags: grafana

I current set the Display Name in Grafana to `${__series.name}`, but this outputs the legend `Series (my_query_name)`

[image]

My legend is set to be `{{display_name}}`

[image]

What I want is to have my legend not show the `Series (x)` and instead show `x`. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could define a transformation "Rename by regexp" on the field and write a regular expression that matches the expected content, e.g.
`Series \((.*)\)`

[image: RegExp Series ((.*))]